# How to render a4j outputpanel from iframe

Tags: jsf, iframe

I have a `a4j:commandButton` in a `iframe` and a `a4j:outputPanel` where both of the iframe and the panel resides in a same page. Is it possible to reRender that panel on that button click?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be not possible to be done using standard JSF+A4J approach. The content inside of `iframe` is build by a separate request to separate view, so it has its own JSF components tree. So `a4j:commandButton` and `a4j:outputPanel` are in different views (different components trees), and it is not possible to do 'cross-tree' rerender.

To access parent page from iframe you can try using JavaScript.

For example put to parent page jsFunction, like this:

```
<a4j:jsFunction name="reRenderPanel" reRender="panelId"/>
```

And in iframe add the following onclick javascript to commandButton:

```
<a4j:commandButton onclick="parent.reRenderPanel();"/>
```

Comment: is `parent.reRenderPanel();` a inbuilt function?

Comment: parent is to get parent page instance, reRenderPanel is a jsFunction name="reRenderPanel"